# How to have $ sign show on a price textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, textbox, datasource, sign

Im coding in VB.Net and trying to have a textbox which displays price with a $ sign. I have gotten it to where the textbox would be empty and once the user puts in a number the sign would show. But I cant add it to the textbox which gets its data from the datasource. If you could lead me towards the direction to get it to show up in the textbox that would be great thanks.

Comment: So, you would let the user type text while you intrusively change that text exactly at the same time as the user types it?. That does not sounds good. why don't just put a label with a "$" symbol together the textbox?.

Comment: No the textbox is getting data from a datasource/database, but it does not currently contain a $ symbol in it. I need to add that symbol and still have the datashow. I'm not sure if the MaskedTextBox is the way or not but I will try that.

Comment: How exactly are you getting the data from the datasource into the textbox? Is the textbox bound to the datasource via databinding?

Comment: I have to connect it without doing a binding. I can browse through the dataset but can display the $ sign and can only display the numbers.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could try the reulting visual behavior of a `MaskedTextBox` control

With for example this mask:

```
MaskedTextBox1.Mask = "9999999999$"
```

Then, to get a integer value when the text has changed:

```
Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles MaskedTextBox1.TextChanged

    Dim mtb As MaskedTextBox = DirectCast(sender, MaskedTextBox)
    Dim intValue As Integer

    If Integer.TryParse(mtb.Text.Replace("$"c, "").Replace(" "c, ""), intValue) Then
        Console.WriteLine(intValue)
    End If

End Sub
```